# How to write a bash script from two commands (Find and replace a text string in all files recursively in current directory)

Tags: command-line, server, bash, 22.04, scripts

On Ubuntu Server, I use two different commands to find and replace a string in all files recursively in the current folder.

1. The first command is:

   ```
   sudo find . -type f -print0 |\
       xargs -0 -r sudo grep -F -l 'my-OLD-custom-string'
   ```

   This commands searches all files recursively in the current folder and lists them. It doesn't do anything else except a search and list so that I can verify that these are the files that I want changed. Once I verify that all the files listed are the files that I want "my-OLD-custom-string" to be replaced with "my-NEW-custom-string", I can proceed to the second command.
2. The second command is:

   ```
   sudo find . -type f -print0 |\
        xargs -0 -r sudo grep -F -l --null 'my-OLD-custom-string' |\
        xargs -0 -r sudo perl -pi~ -e 's/my-OLD-custom-string/my-NEW-custom-string/g'
   ```

   This command will find "`my-OLD-custom-string`" in the files in the current directory recursively, replace them with "`my-NEW-custom-string`", and leave my original unmodified files as `filename~`, for recovery, just in case.

I would like to put these commands into a bash script so that it looks reads/works like this:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ ls -la
total 40964
drwxrwxr-x  2 Danran Danran     4096 Mar  2 19:17 .
drwxr-x--- 20 Danran Danran     4096 Mar 13 15:02 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 Danran Danran 16380529 Sep 15 18:50 test_text1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Danran Danran      870 Feb 14 11:51 test_text2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Danran Danran     3129 Dec 22  2017 test_text3.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Danran Danran    12693 Jan 20  2022 test_text4.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Danran Danran        0 Mar 13 15:59 custom_bash_script.sh
$ cat test_text1.txt
my-OLD-custom-string
$ ./custom_bash_script.sh
Enter the text string you are searching for:
Text string here: my-OLD-custom-string
[sudo] password for Danran: ****************
Here are the listed files with your inputted text string:
./test_text1.txt
Would you like to replace the string "my-OLD-custom-string" in the above listed files?: y
What do you want the new string to be?: my-NEW-custom-string
The old string has now been replaced with the new string in the above requested files.
$ cat test_text1.txt
my-NEW-custom-string
```

Here is the script that I have so far but it's not working at all...

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter the text string you are searching for:"
read -p "Text string here: " textstringold
sudo find . -type f -name "$textstringold"
sudo find . -type f -print0 |\
     xargs -0 -r sudo grep -F -l --null "$textstringold" |\
     xargs -0 -r sudo perl -pi~ -e "s/$textstringold/$textstringnew/g"
```

Could someone please help me write this script to the desired specifications so that is is working as stated above? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If the task is to find files and texts in your own folder why are you using all these `sudo`?

Comment: In case I want to use the same script in the root folder. @user68186

Comment: `cd $PWD` will not take anywhere except where you currently are ... `"$textstringold` is missing the final double quote ... `'$textstringold'` will not expand inside single quotes (use double quotes `"..."`) ... Same for the two parameters in `'s/$textstringold/$textstringnew/g'` will not expand inside single quotes as well.

Comment: Then you should run the script like so: `sudo custom_bash_script.sh` and get rid of all the sudo from inside.

Comment: ... And please don't use that script at all as it will most likely do what you expect ... e.g. have a closer look at `find . -type f -name "$textstringold"` that is searching filenames and not contents ... and `$textstringnew` is not set so will expand to a blank and mess up your files contents.

Comment: ... most likely **not** do what you expect ... :-) typo

Answer (score 1):

This site is not a script-writing site, but help to anyone on planet Earth is a strong motive in this community (*no discrimination against beings from other planets :-) thogh*).

That said, take the following script as a template/boilerplate to get you going and please don't ask for improvements but improve it yourself instead or ask a new separate question if you have to ...

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read -r -p "You are in \"$PWD\". Is this the right directory? [y(es)|n(o)|q(uit): "; do
  case "$REPLY" in
    y) read -r -p "Pleas, enter the search string: "
       readarray -d '' files < <(grep -rF -l --null "$REPLY")
       if [[ "${#files[@]}" -eq 0 ]]; then
         printf '%s\n' "no matches found ... exiting"
         unset files
         exit
       else
         search="$REPLY"
         printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" | less
         read -r -p "Matches found ${#files[@]}. Pleas, enter the replacement string: "
         replacement="$REPLY"
         printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" |
         xargs -0 -r perl -p -e "s/${search}/${replacement}/g"
       fi
       unset files
       exit
       ;;
   n) while true; do
        read -r -p "Enter the correct directory path: "
        if ! [ -z "$REPLY" ]; then
          cd "$REPLY" && break
          fi
        done
        ;;
   q) exit
      ;;
   *) printf '%s\n' "Invalid input"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

You'll need to save that to a file and make that file executable before you can run the script.

**Notice** I intentionally removed the in-place editing option from the Perl command for your safety, so the script will only print out modifications to files contents but no actual editing will be done ... You'll need to add that option to the Perl command after you verify that is safe.